# Apache subdomains configuration with cPanel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I have configured 2 subdomains on my hosting. 
On one drupal is installed and it works fine. 
http://drup.highlander.ge/
On another I have put only html file and redirection to subdomain doesn't work
austral.highlander.ge goes to http://www.georgia-tours.eu/austral/

(www.georgia-tours.eu is redirected to highlander.ge in htaccess)

In htaccess I hadn't made anything. Actually neither drupal has done. There are only main domain's wordpress records.

How to make it work?

Here is htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx   index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml index.htm home.htm default.htm index.fcgi default.html
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW REDIRECTID:qPNG5C
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^georgia-tours.eu$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} highlander.ge$


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /ru/ru http://www.georgia-tours.eu/ru/

Redirect 301 /tours/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/category/tours/

Redirect 301 /ru/tours/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/ru/category/tours/

Redirect 301 /uk/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/ru/

Redirect 301 /flights-from-tbilisi-to-mestia/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/travel-forum/topic/tbilisi-mestia-flights/

Redirect 301 /ru/flights-from-tbilisi-to-mestia/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/ru/travel-forum/topic/tbilisi-mestia-flights/

Redirect 301 /tours/winter-tours/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/category/tours/wintertours/

Redirect 301 /horse-tours/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/category/tours/horse-tours/

Redirect 301 /ru/horse-tours/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/ru/category/tours/horse-tours/

Redirect 301 /ru/about-georgia/attractions-of-georgia/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/ru/category/places-of-interest/

Redirect 301 /about-georgia/attractions-of-georgia/ http://www.georgia-tours.eu/category/places-of-interest/

RewriteRule ^mail$ http://gmail.com/a/highlander.ge [R=301,L]

# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]


Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"


## EXPIRES CACHING ##

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"

## EXPIRES CACHING ##

# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE qPNG5C:REDIRECTID
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript   application/json
</ifModule>
```

Comment: is georgia-tours.eu your primary domain?

Comment: post your .htaccess file here.

Comment: Posted htaccess in message

Comment: might be wrong (havent dont .htaccess in a while but add this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^austral.highlander.ge$` followed by

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://austral.highlander.ge/$1 [R=permanent,L]`

Comment: you need this `Redirect 301 /austral http://austral.highlender.eu`

Comment: No it returns This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: are you putting at the start before `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^georgia-tours.eu$
`

Comment: The webpage at http://austral.highlander.ge/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/austral/ has resulted in too many redirects.